# .lower is not working for my code in pycharm

Tags: python, lowercase

I am new to python and here is my code and .lower usually works but this time it isn't.

```
technical_dict = {
        dict : 'stores a key/value pair',
        list : 'stores a value at each index',
        map : 'see dict',
        set : 'stores unordered unique elements'
    }

    userInput = (input("What term would you like to lookup or type 'exit' to stop:"))
    if userInput.lower() not in technical_dict:
        print("Term does not exist in technical dictionary")
    if userInput.lower()  in technical_dict:
        print(technical_dict[userInput.lower()])
        while userInput.lower() != "exit":
            userInput = input("What term would you like to lookup or type 'exit' to stop:")
            if userInput.lower() in technical_dict:
        print(technical_dict[userInput.lower()])
            if userInput.lower() not in technical_dict:
                print("Term does not exist in technical dictionary")
                break
```

Comment: What is the error that you receive?

Comment: Are your keys types?

Comment: This is the error I get - AttributeError: type object 'dict' has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: Does your keys in `technical_dict` arent string on purpose? Moreover, I guess that uou want to check the input over `technical_dict.keys()` and not just `technical_dict`

Comment: This is the full traceback Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 9, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'dict' has no attribute 'lower'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with how you are creating your dictionary. The key values that you have right now are not of type string, or str. This is why you are getting the error that a dict has no attribute 'lower'. To fix it you would change the values so that they are of type string. Try this:

```
technical_dict = {
        'dict' : 'stores a key/value pair',
        'list' : 'stores a value at each index',
        'map' : 'see dict',
        'set' : 'stores unordered unique elements'
    }
```